# JavaFX DPI awarness

Tags: java, javafx, screen-resolution, dpi, scenebuilder

Good night, I'm making an application using javaFx with some partners; the idea is that it's going to be used in Windows and Linux. We've been doing some testing and seen that the application displays different in both OS.

We are using Scene Builder.I'm wondering if someone happend to come across a similar problem and how you solve it(I've already read other similar post but none of them helped me).

This is how it displays on Windows:
[image]

And this is how it displays on Linux:
[image]

This is just one example as it happens with all forms. If there's someone out there that could help, we would really appreciate it!!

I made the next function to call the forms:

```
private void OpenForm(String form, String title) {
    try
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(form));
        Parent root;
        root = fxmlLoader1.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Msg(3,"Program error","It appears there's something wrong : ",ex.getMessage().toString());
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Here's the FXML of the form as requested:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

    <AnchorPane prefHeight="346.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="GUI.Almacen.ClientesMod">
       <children>
       <TableView fx:id="tvClientes" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="638.0">
       <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="tcIdCliente" prefWidth="75.0" text="RacF de Cliente" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="tcNombre" prefWidth="75.0" text="Nombre" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="tcDivision" prefWidth="75.0" text="División" />
    </columns>
     <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
     </columnResizePolicy>
  </TableView>
  <Button fx:id="btnModificar" disable="true" layoutX="535.0" layoutY="320.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#abrirModificarCliente" text="Modificar Cliente" />
  <Button fx:id="btnAgregar" layoutX="432.0" layoutY="320.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#abrirAgregarCliente" text="Agregar Cliente" />
    </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It just looks like different fonts are changing the size of the buttons. Can you post the code?

Comment: I posted the code that I use to call all the forms, whatever else you need Im happy to post it, is not so much space as it is the spacing between the different controls of the form.

Comment: Take a look at the application using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) on both OS to figure out what the actual difference is. The relevant code is in the FXML and CSS files that you should then add to the post.

Comment: I meant the layout code. Can you post the FXML?

Comment: There it is. I dont know if the problem is originated by the layout or the windows manager, I hope you have some ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all very much for commenting, The problem was the font family and size as Linux wasn't recognizing them, what I did was download a font file and add it to the proyect, create a *.css file with:

```
    @font-face {
         src: url("Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    }

    .root {
        -fx-font-family: "Roboto Regular";
        -fx-font-size: 12px;
     }
```

And then add it to the scene before opening it with :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/stock/css.css").toExternalForm());
```

Even though the problem is solved and it looks great, there's still the tiny detail that when im designing I have to take out the spaces to the right and bottom because Windows add more of it, that doesn't seem to be happening on Linux so there's a difference in display.

Answer (score 1):

The windows default Font is different from the Linux default Font you are running on. To check this please set a pre-defined object and see

in your TableCell

```
{
   setFont(Font.font(Font.getFontNames().get(4), size));
}
```